# Edit mode of baked cloth

Tags: edit-mode, baking, cloth-simulation

I am doing this [interior tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4G9cMi8QAa4) of Blender Guru and at min 31:50 he is doing some changes at a curtain. This is my scene in object mode

[image]

When Blender Guru selects the curtain and goes to edit mode he gets this

[image]

but when I do that I get this

[image]

So he gets the edit mode of the baked object and I get the edit mode of the object before baking ??? What should I do to get the edit mode of the baked object ?

Comment: The explanation seems to be around 26:30 / 27:15. He applied the subsurf and the cloth simulation. So after that he just keeps the mesh shown in your second picture.

Comment: yes, you are right. I missed that. I did wonder why he copied the curtains and moved it to another layer. Now I understand, it was his backup for when he needed the object before applying the modifiers

Comment: yes, I understood it the same way : a backup

Comment: I still think I would prefer to do that apply at a later moment, maybe when finishing up the scene

Comment: well... my level is not good enough to say more about Blender Guru reasons for it... But yes you can do it later, surely, except if this is not compatible to the texture approach (many more time is needed to check that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see the miracle happen in minute 27:00 of the tutorial, BlenderGuru applies both modifiers, which effectively removes the simulation and bakes the mesh at that condition into the object. As soon as modifiers are applied, no more changes are possible.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to click "Apply" on the modifier in the modifier stack at 27:00. Either that, or you applied the modifier as a shape key, and you need to "turn on" the shape key by setting it's influence to 1.0